# jquery AJAX serialization of repeated params in GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parameters, get

I have such data:

```
data = {
    someID: Number,
    someList: [
       {a:1,b:2}
       {a:2, b:3}
    ]
}
```

I want using $.ajax make GET requests sutch as:

```
?someID=Number&a=1&b=2&a=2&b=3
```

Could anybody point me at better way how to do it?

Comment: If you are using jQuery, you can try this: $.param(data)

Answer (score 0):

```
    var url = '?someID='+data['someID'];
    for (l in data['someList']) {
        url += '&a=' + data['someList'][l]['a'] + '&b=' + data['someList'][l]['b'];
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: #your url,
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'dataType' : 'json'
    })
    .done(function (resp) {
        # your done function
    });
```

Of course all of this would be possible, if you know all your indexes.

Comment: I've used this method, but this is exactly what I wanted to avoid. Thanks for support.

Comment: Confused. U used my method, or u used it before I suggested it?

Comment: I knew that I could do it in that way before you had suggested me it. But I was hoping that is exist a prettier method but after your answer I understood that there is no hope =)